# Select Distinct

Tags: mysql, distinct

```
tbl_protocolos

id_protocolo | protocolo | assunto

1;ra001;vazamentos

2;ra002;incendios

3;ra003;inundacoes


tbl_prot_tramitacoes

id_tram | id_protocolo | pdf | id_setor_origem

1;1;001.pdf;70

2;1;001.pdf;100 - **rejeitar por causa do id_setor_origem**

3;2;002.pdf;70

4;3;003.pdf;70

5;1;001.pdf;70 - rejeitar pois já peguei **id_protocolo = 1** na linha 1
```

Eu preciso do campo pdf da tbl_prot_tramitacoes ( onde há repetição do `id_protocolo` ) e `id_setor_origem = 70` 
e preciso tb do campo protocolo e assunto da tbl_protocolos ( onde NAO há repetiçao do `id_protocolo` )

Agora, como eu trago esses registros ?

```
id_tram | protocolo | assunto | pdf

1          ra001    vazamentos  001.pdf

3          ra002    incendios   002.pdf

4          ra003    inundacoes  003.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma subquery para selecionar as linhas que atendem as condições, como mostrado abaixo.

```sql
SELECT a.id_tram,protocolo, assunto, pdf 
FROM tbl_prot_tramitacoes AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_protocolos AS b
ON a.id_protocolo = b.id_protocolo
WHERE a.id_tram IN 
(SELECT MIN(id_tram)
FROM tbl_prot_tramitacoes
WHERE id_setor_origem = 70
GROUP BY id_protocolo)
```

O select dentro dos parêntesis é usado para obter o id das linhas com primeira ocorrência de cada `id_protocolo`. Depois, no select de cima, utiliza-se esses ids para obter as informações adicionais.

Comment: Show de bola. Lição aprendida. Muito Obrigado. Além de resolver a questão comentou como funciona e isso pra mim foi sensacional.

Comment: SELECT b.id_protocolo, b.protocolo, b.assunto, b.assunto, a.numero_doc, a.pdf, a.data_tramitacao 
FROM tbl_prot_tramitacoes AS a 
INNER JOIN tbl_protocolos AS b ON 
a.id_protocolo = b.id_protocolo 
WHERE a.id_tramitacao IN (SELECT MIN(id_tramitacao) 
                          FROM tbl_prot_tramitacoes 
                          WHERE id_setor_origem = 70 GROUP BY id_protocolo)
 
Uma pergunta, existe alguma forma DENTRO DESSA query de ADICIONAR uma coluna DIFERENÇA que mostre a diferença de DIAS entre a.data_tramitacao e o dia de HOJE ?

Comment: Sim, vc pode usar a função `DATEDIFF` para obter a diferença entre duas datas, e usar `NOW()` para obter o dia de hoje. `DATEDIFF(now(),a.data_tramitacao)`

Comment: Obrigado, show de bola

Comment: @theteo Neste caso (comentário anterior) a diferença é gerada na hora que se faz o select, não acho que faça sentido _adicionar_ uma coluna com esse conteúdo na tabela, já que ele vai depender do momento em que se lê a mesma.

Comment: entendi, mas eu irei usar essa query pra gerar uma VIEW, então no meu caso vai fazer todo sentido. Obrigado.

Comment: @theteo Sim, no caso de uma view faz sentido. De nada!